# How can I connect the individual data points between split violin plots in python plotly?

Tags: python, plotly, plotly-python, violin-plot

How can I connect the individual data points between split violin plots in python plotly?

Example code:

```
from plotly import graph_objs as go
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(data=[["2021.01", "test1", 1.1], ["2021.01", "test1", 1.2], ["2021.01", "test1", 1.3], ["2021.01", "test1", 1.4], ["2021.01", "test1", 1.5], ["2021.01", "test1", 1.6],
                        ["2021.02", "test1", 1.2], ["2021.02", "test1", 1.3], ["2021.02", "test1", 1.4], ["2021.02", "test1", 1.5], ["2021.02", "test1", 1.6], ["2021.02", "test1", 1.7],
                        ["2021.01", "test2", 1.5], ["2021.01", "test2", 1.6], ["2021.01", "test2", 1.7], ["2021.01", "test2", 1.8], ["2021.01", "test2", 1.9], ["2021.01", "test2", 2.0],
                        ["2021.02", "test2", 1.7], ["2021.02", "test2", 1.8], ["2021.02", "test2", 1.9], ["2021.02", "test2", 2.0], ["2021.02", "test2", 2.1], ["2021.02", "test2", 2.2]],
                  columns=["date", "test", "values"],
                  index=["A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F",
                         "A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F",
                         "A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F",
                         "A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F"]
                 )

fig = go.Figure()

filter = "2021.01"
fig.add_trace(go.Violin(x = df[df["date"]==filter]["test"],
                        y = df[df["date"]==filter]["values"],
                        text = df[df["date"]==filter].index,
                        name = filter,
                        side = "negative",
                        pointpos = -1.5,
                       ))

filter = "2021.02"
fig.add_trace(go.Violin(x = df[df["date"]==filter]["test"],
                        y = df[df["date"]==filter]["values"],
                        text = df[df["date"]==filter].index,
                        name = filter,
                        side = "positive",
                        pointpos = 1.5,
                       ))

fig.update_traces(meanline_visible = True,
                  points="all",
                  jitter = 0.05,
                  scalemode = "count",
                 )

fig.show()
```

[Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nrj38.png):

[image]

Instead of the original output, I would like to have a line for the F data set as shown here:

[Desired output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5OEwO.png)

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using r-beginners answer I came up with a dynamic solution using pointpos. It works if there are only 2 violin plots.

Original code changed slightly (added pointpos as a variable and added an index to filter):

```
from plotly import graph_objs as go
import pandas as pd

pointpos = 1.5
filter_1 = "2021.01"
filter_2 = "2021.02"

df = pd.DataFrame(data=[["2021.01", "test1", 1.1], ["2021.01", "test1", 1.2], ["2021.01", "test1", 1.3], ["2021.01", "test1", 1.4], ["2021.01", "test1", 1.5], ["2021.01", "test1", 1.6],
                        ["2021.02", "test1", 1.2], ["2021.02", "test1", 1.3], ["2021.02", "test1", 1.4], ["2021.02", "test1", 1.5], ["2021.02", "test1", 1.6], ["2021.02", "test1", 1.7],
                        ["2021.01", "test2", 1.5], ["2021.01", "test2", 1.6], ["2021.01", "test2", 1.7], ["2021.01", "test2", 1.8], ["2021.01", "test2", 1.9], ["2021.01", "test2", 2.0],
                        ["2021.02", "test2", 1.7], ["2021.02", "test2", 1.8], ["2021.02", "test2", 1.9], ["2021.02", "test2", 2.0], ["2021.02", "test2", 2.1], ["2021.02", "test2", 2.2]],
                  columns=["date", "test", "values"],
                  index=["A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F",
                         "A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F",
                         "A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F",
                         "A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F"]
                 )

fig = go.Figure()


fig.add_trace(go.Violin(x = df[df["date"]==filter_1]["test"],
                        y = df[df["date"]==filter_1]["values"],
                        text = df[df["date"]==filter_1].index,
                        name = filter_1,
                        side = "negative",
                        pointpos = -pointpos,
                       ))


fig.add_trace(go.Violin(x = df[df["date"]==filter_2]["test"],
                        y = df[df["date"]==filter_2]["values"],
                        text = df[df["date"]==filter_2].index,
                        name = filter_2,
                        side = "positive",
                        pointpos = pointpos,
                       ))


fig.update_traces(meanline_visible = True,
                  points="all",
                  jitter = 0.05,
                  scalemode = "count",
                 )

fig.show()
```

r-beginner's answer changed slightly (changed xref="paper" to xref="x" and made the line positions more dynamic):

```
filter_letter = "F"
lines = df[df.index==filter_letter]

filter_test_1 = "test1"
filter_test_2 = "test2"

fig.add_shape(type='line',
              x0=-pointpos/4,
              x1=pointpos/4,
              y0=float(lines[(lines["date"]==filter_1) & (lines["test"]==filter_test_1)]["values"]),
              y1=float(lines[(lines["date"]==filter_2) & (lines["test"]==filter_test_1)]["values"]),
              xref='x',
              yref='y',
              line=dict(
                  color='RoyalBlue',
                  width=2
              )
             )
fig.add_shape(type='line',
              x0=pointpos/4,
              x1=1-pointpos/4,
              y0=float(lines[(lines["date"]==filter_2) & (lines["test"]==filter_test_1)]["values"]),
              y1=float(lines[(lines["date"]==filter_1) & (lines["test"]==filter_test_2)]["values"]),
              xref='x',
              yref='y',
              line=dict(
                  color='RoyalBlue',
                  width=2
              )
             )

fig.add_shape(type='line',
              x0=1-pointpos/4,
              x1=1+pointpos/4,
              y0=float(lines[(lines["date"]==filter_1) & (lines["test"]==filter_test_2)]["values"]),
              y1=float(lines[(lines["date"]==filter_2) & (lines["test"]==filter_test_2)]["values"]),
              xref='x',
              yref='y',
              line=dict(
                  color='RoyalBlue',
                  width=2
              )
             )

fig.show()
```

see code's output: [code's output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8e8En.png)

Note that the violin plot's pointpos and the xref's scales are different, see below a picture that explains:
[pointpos vs xref](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G7TkF.png)

Answer (score 0):

I tried to get the maximum value of each and add a line chart to the category data, but it did not work. The position of the x-axis is set manually, so the optimal value needs to be found. x-axis can be set based on the graph area, and y-axis can be set based on the y-axis.

```
lines = df.groupby(['date','test'])['values'].max().to_frame('values')

fig.add_shape(type='line',
              x0=0.055,
              x1=0.45,
              y0=lines.values[0][0],
              y1=lines.values[2][0],
              xref='paper',
              yref='y',
              line=dict(
                  color='RoyalBlue',
                  width=2
              )
             )
fig.add_shape(type='line',
              x0=0.45,
              x1=0.55,
              y0=lines.values[2][0],
              y1=lines.values[1][0],
              xref='paper',
              yref='y',
              line=dict(
                  color='RoyalBlue',
                  width=2
              )
             )

fig.add_shape(type='line',
              x0=0.55,
              x1=0.95,
              y0=lines.values[1][0],
              y1=lines.values[3][0],
              xref='paper',
              yref='y',
              line=dict(
                  color='RoyalBlue',
                  width=2
              )
             )

fig.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Good start! My only problem is that zoom in / out breaks the image due to xref="paper"

Comment: That was an omission of consideration, wasn't it? I'm glad my response helped you answer your own question. I vote +1 for your answer.

Answer (score 0):

I'm glad you found a solution that works for you. In your code you have to specify `pointpos = 1.5`, which isn't too far off when it comes to the x-axis values. If you're willing to specify x-values instead of pointpos, the code snippet below will produce the following plot using `fig=make_subplots()` for the trace, and  this little snippet to find all `y-values` dynamically:

```
# find correct Y values
lineY = []
for j, t in enumerate(df.test.unique()):
    dfd = df[df.test == t]
    for i, d in enumerate(dfd.date.unique()):
        dft = dfd[dfd.date == d]
        lineY.append(dft['values'].max())
```

#### Plot:

[image]

#### Complete code:

```
from plotly import graph_objs as go
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(data=[["2021.01", "test1", 1.1], ["2021.01", "test1", 1.2], ["2021.01", "test1", 1.3], ["2021.01", "test1", 1.4], ["2021.01", "test1", 1.5], ["2021.01", "test1", 1.6],
                        ["2021.02", "test1", 1.2], ["2021.02", "test1", 1.3], ["2021.02", "test1", 1.4], ["2021.02", "test1", 1.5], ["2021.02", "test1", 1.6], ["2021.02", "test1", 1.7],
                        ["2021.01", "test2", 1.5], ["2021.01", "test2", 1.6], ["2021.01", "test2", 1.7], ["2021.01", "test2", 1.8], ["2021.01", "test2", 1.9], ["2021.01", "test2", 2.0],
                        ["2021.02", "test2", 1.7], ["2021.02", "test2", 1.8], ["2021.02", "test2", 1.9], ["2021.02", "test2", 2.0], ["2021.02", "test2", 2.1], ["2021.02", "test2", 2.2]],
                  columns=["date", "test", "values"],
                  index=["A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F",
                         "A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F",
                         "A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F",
                         "A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F"]
                 )

# fig = go.Figure()
import numpy as np
import plotly.graph_objects as go
from plotly.subplots import make_subplots

fig=make_subplots(
        specs=[[{"secondary_y": True}]])
# print(fig.layout)    

fig.update_layout(xaxis2= {'anchor': 'y', 'overlaying': 'x', 'side': 'top'},
#                   yaxis_domain=[0, 0.94]
                 )

filter = "2021.01"
fig.add_trace(go.Violin(x = df[df["date"]==filter]["test"],
                        y = df[df["date"]==filter]["values"],
                        text = df[df["date"]==filter].index,
                        name = filter,
                        side = "negative",
                        pointpos = -1.5,
                       ))

filter = "2021.02"
fig.add_trace(go.Violin(x = df[df["date"]==filter]["test"],
                        y = df[df["date"]==filter]["values"],
                        text = df[df["date"]==filter].index,
                        name = filter,
                        side = "positive",
                        pointpos = 1.5,
                       ))

fig.update_traces(meanline_visible = True,
                  points="all",
                  jitter = 0.0,
                  scalemode = "count",
                 )

fig.update_traces(marker_size = 10)
fig.update_layout(xaxis2_tickfont_color = 'rgba(0,0,0,0)')

# find correct Y values
lineY = []
for j, t in enumerate(df.test.unique()):
    dfd = df[df.test == t]
    for i, d in enumerate(dfd.date.unique()):
        dft = dfd[dfd.date == d]
        lineY.append(dft['values'].max())
        
# make up corresponding x values
lineX = [1,2.27,2.73,4]

fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(x=lineX, y = lineY, mode = 'markers+lines', name = 'max',
                         marker_size = 4,
                         line_color = 'black'))
fig.data[2].update(xaxis='x2')
fig.show()
```